# How to change Gtk3 StackSwitcher Controls' Alignment

Tags: python-3.x, layout, gtk3

I'd like to use a Gtk3 Stack Switcher as my layout container and was just wondering if it is,by any means,possible to change the control buttons' alignment to say **VERTICAL** because by default they are shown in a  row and they are horizontally aligned

PS:I want to change the alignment of the controls themselves not the contents of the stack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. [Gtk.StackSwitcher](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/StackSwitcher.html) implements the [Gtk.Orientable](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/Orientable.html#Gtk.Orientable) interface and inherits from Gtk.Box

If using [glade](https://glade.gnome.org/), there is a combobox in the widget General attributes tab which allows choosing the orientation.

You can also do it programmatically, using the [Gtk.Orientable](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/Orientable.html#Gtk.Orientable) method [`set_orientation`](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/Orientable.html#Gtk.Orientable.set_orientation):

```
...    
stack_switcher = Gtk.StackSwitcher()
stack_switcher.set_stack(stack)
stack_switcher.set_orientation(Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL)
...
```

Let's take the Python Gtk+ 3 [Stack and StackSwitcher tutorial example](https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/layout.html#id3) and change the stack switcher orientation:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

class StackWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Stack Demo")
        self.set_border_width(10)

        vbox = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL, spacing=6)
        self.add(vbox)

        stack = Gtk.Stack()
        stack.set_transition_type(Gtk.StackTransitionType.SLIDE_LEFT_RIGHT)
        stack.set_transition_duration(1000)

        checkbutton = Gtk.CheckButton("Click me!")
        stack.add_titled(checkbutton, "check", "Check Button")

        label = Gtk.Label()
        label.set_markup("<big>A fancy label</big>")
        stack.add_titled(label, "label", "A label")

        stack_switcher = Gtk.StackSwitcher()
        stack_switcher.set_stack(stack)
        stack_switcher.set_orientation(Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL)
        vbox.pack_start(stack_switcher, True, True, 0)
        vbox.pack_start(stack, True, True, 0)

win = StackWindow()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

The expected result is:

[image]

a vertical Gtk.StackSwitcher.

Comment: thanks man,i had no idea...another question,that 'click me' combo box,how can i put it on the left of the window,e.g besides 'check button' or 'a label'??

Comment: @silverhash It seems you are after [Gtk.Notebook](https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/layout.html#notebook) "look". The shown example container layout it's not the best for your needs. There is a Vertical GtkBox with the stack switcher on the top and the stack on the bottom child container. Then the toplevel window, imposes a spacing of 10px and that's why the widgets are not immediately after the window. Set the border width to 0 and the main Gtk.Box container to HORIZONTAL and the result should more similar to what you need

Answer (score 1):

@Jose Fonte,thanks bro....i took your advice and tried to use it,After a while though,I descovered something else that was way easier to fix my problem.A [Gtk.StackSideBar](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/StackSidebar.html#Gtk.StackSidebar).So i ended up using that as this is exactly what i was after

Comment: Yes indeed, i forgot it. Good. I've edited you answer to link it to the PyGObject API. Good luck.